# In Oracle Can i refer a VARRAY in MERGE syntax this way?

Tags: oracle, merge, varray

The following produces a error:
[Error] ORA-00904 (265: 19): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "INP"."COLUMN_VALUE": invalid identifier

```
  MERGE INTO tab_mapping tbl_llclm
       USING (
              SELECT COLUMN_VALUE as map_id
                FROM TABLE (p_llcl_map_array) inp)
          ON (inp.COLUMN_VALUE = tbl_llclm.lab_loinc_map_id)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN
     INSERT     (tab_map_id,
                 tab_loinc_map_id,
                 last_updated_by,
                 last_updated_date)
         VALUES (p_llc_id,
                 inp.map_id,
                 p_last_updated_by,
                 SYSDATE);
```

p_llcl_map_array is of type num_arr (num_arr is SQL type TABLE of number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I just moved the alias `inp` outside and referred the `COLUMN_VALUE` by `map_id`

```
MERGE INTO tab_mapping tbl_llclm
       USING (
              SELECT COLUMN_VALUE as map_id
                FROM TABLE (p_llcl_map_array) 
             ) inp
          ON (inp.map_id = tbl_llclm.lab_loinc_map_id)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN
     INSERT     (tab_map_id,
                 tab_loinc_map_id,
                 last_updated_by,
                 last_updated_date)
         VALUES (p_llc_id,
                 inp.map_id,
                 p_last_updated_by,
                 SYSDATE);
```

Comment: Thank you Maheswaran. You saw what i overlooked :-)